# Extract BLOB polygon from MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob, polygon

I am developing a web application that stores polygons in a database using jsf. I am able to store the polygon in a field of a row using the **POLYGON** datatype in **MySQL**, the polygon then appears as a **BLOB** in the database.

However I am unsure on how to access the polygon in each row using row-sets in JDBC. Ideally I would like to convert this data from a POLYGON BLOB to a **LatLng array**.

I am aware that it can be returned as a **WKT** using MYSQL

```
(SELECT * ST_AsText(markers) FROM paddock)
```

but I'm just unsure how to access it in Java. If anyone has any ideas, please feel free to share, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. I used the above MySQL statement that returns a string value and used java regular expression in order to extract the coordinates

```
                    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
                    String value = rs.getString(1);
                    String valuereal = value.replaceAll("[^0-9 .,]+", "");
                    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(valuereal.split(",")));
```

The regular expression above only allows numbers, dots and commas from the BLOB POLYGON type in MySQL, then a split is used to store it in a string array.